# Is SRH recombination synonymous with all phonon-assisted nonradiative processes?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Is Shockley-Read-Hall recombination synonymous with all phonon-assisted nonradiative processes? In organic molecules, "internal conversion" is used to describe non-radiative decay from excited states. It seems like nonradiative recombination can take many forms (including Auger Recombination, recombination at defects and recombination at surfaces). Looking for clarification.